# How to access "current cell output area" with JavaScript in IPython Web notebook?

Tags: javascript, ipython

In the IPython Web notebook, I'm writing code that returns a JavaScript display object, that will display output in the cell output area.

What's the preferred idiom for the JavaScript code to reference "the current cell's output area", in a way that doesn't overlap things if there are multiple JavaScript output cells in the notebook?

(I realize that IPython JavaScript support is a work in progress).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot easily get access to the output area, but when javascript is executed, it is in a namespace where a hidden div bind to a local variable named <del>`container`</del> `element`  exist and is **in** the output area. <del>you can `.show()`</del>  it and inject html in it it will appear where you expect it to.

See for example http://nbviewer.ipython.org/6131622

UPDATE IPython 2.0 and above.

Starting with IPython 2.0 you should access the DOM via a local variable named `element` in which you can append whatever you like. This tag is invisible when empty and will be automatically shown when not empty (it use a css `:empty` pseudo selector to apply `display:none` css rule).

For compatibility reason the old methods might still work for IPython version 2.0.

Comment: Updating this for the notebook 2.x and beyond: is "element" the preferred variable to reference for the output area?

Comment: IRC using element is not supported. You should use `container` and append to it. No need to call show anymore.

Comment: Are you sure?  The docs say `element`:  http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.display.html (though the docs also still say you need to call `container.show()`).

Comment: I'll check, i'm 95% certain you do not need to use `container.show()` as the frontend css now get a `container:empty{display:none}`css.

Comment: 'container.show()' is definitely no longer needed.  I'm just trying to confirm that `element` is the preferred idiom for output area access, not `container`.  (and if so, we should update your answer).

Comment: The doc has been updated, and the code state that container will be removed in 3.0 now. I'll update my answer.